# How do I integrate blog site in to my own site?

Tags: dasblog

I am using DasBlog version 1.9.7174.1, what I am trying to do is to integrate this web blog site in to my own site, but DasBlog is running localhost perfectly, and I dont know how to integrate this in to my own site,  can some one help me on this please?

Has anybody got any experience on integrating any other blog engines in to your own site?

If yes, could someone help me on this?

Thanks
suis

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic approaches:

1. Edit the templates to match the design of the rest of the site
2. Extract the data from the system and insert it into the CMS used elsewhere on the site

Comment: hi David,
thanks for the quick answer, well the site i have written in asp.net (c#) running on ASP.Net 1.1 , i realy didnt get your point 

"Extract the data from the system and insert it into the CMS used elsewhere on the site "     ----- Whats this mean ?

Comment: The blog software will store the data somewhere. The rest of the site stores its data somewhere else. Write something to copy the data from one to the other. Use an API if the blog software provides one (e.g. an Atom/RSS feed).